User has empty instead of custom role when logged in
I am doing custom registration and logging and assigning a custom user role.
I register like this:
$user_id = wp_create_user($username, $password, $email);

            if (!is_wp_error($user_id)) {
                $user = new WP_User($user_id);
                $user->set_role('user');

                echo __('Registration successful.', 'vk-add-and-review');
            } else {
                echo __('Registration failed.', 'vk-add-and-review');
            }

In wp_usermeta wp_capabilities I have this: a:1:{s:4:"user";b:1;}
Still, when I check for the user after logging in it is empty:
if (is_user_logged_in()) {
            $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
            if (in_array('user', (array) $current_user->roles)) {
                return '<p>' . __('You are logged in as a user.', 'vk-add-and-review') . '</p>';
            } else {
                return '<p>' . __('You are logged in, but not as a user.', 'vk-add-and-review') . '</p>';
            }
        }

$current_user->roles is an empty array

is this a multisite? User roles are per site not per install, assigning a user a role on one site won't mean they have that role on every site in the multisite install, just the one that the code ran for. There's also no such thing as an empty role but it is possible for a user to have no roles at all on a site. Also WordPress doesn't have a role named users, is this something you've added? If so where did you add it and can we see the code? And where/when is the code in your question running? init hook? A template?

Yea it's a custom role as I have stated, I guess the issue is the role needs to be added globally before being assigned.

have you tried switching to wp_insert_user and telling it to set the role all at once rather than creating a WP_User and calling set_role? Note that a role is intended to provide capabilities and it's the capabilities not the role that you check for, that way you could do current_user_can( 'thing' ) or $user->has_cap( 'thing' ) where thing is a capability the user role has been granted.

No but I will have a look, thanks. The thing is I wanted custom registration for users that shouldn't have access to the backend with any capability, so I thought creating a custom role is the way to go.
